# Best Implementation for MySite

Tags: 2010, my-site, site-collection

I'm currently looking into adding the MySite feature to my SharePoint setup at my business, and have a few questions:

1. Should I make my MySite in a separate "MySite" collection away from the main site I have?
2. If I were to make this separate, will the data in the different collections be able to communicate with each other?
3. If the above option is not the best practice for implementing the MySite feature, what is?

Thanks guys. If you guys need any clarification of what I'm asking, please just ask!

Answer (score 1):

It's best to have MySites in its own site collection, preferably in its own web application as well. This separation provides improved management capabilities. The My Sites, since it is its own web application, cannot easily obtain info from other site collections (there's no easy OOTB methods for cross site collection aggregation).